# join - file is on sorted

Tags: sorting, join

I tried join two files, but I don't know why join doesn't listen to me.

File i:

```
1 afjsadfjasdf
3 afdadsfa
4 afjdsakjfads
5 asdfadsfads
9 asfadsfads
```

File k:

```
1 fdasdfadsfads
2 dfasjfadsjfas
3 dsafadsfadsf
4 asfdasdfadsf
9 asdfadsfadsfa
10 adsfadsfa
```

My command:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 i k >ik
```

And error:

```
join: k:6: is not sorted: 10 adsfadsfa
```

Could you tell me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--nocheck-order`to make it work. The change from 1 digit to 2 digits produce the error. Also, by default, join compares the first column of each file, you don't need the `-1 1 -2 1` part.

Comment: @diego9403, To expand, `join` requires the files to be sorted **lexically**. According to the dictionary, the word "10" goes after "1" but before "2". Another way to write your command: `join -j 1 <(sort i) <(sort k)`

Comment: @glennjackman I had already applied the `--nocheck-order` solution but I was still wondering why does it behave like that and there is no mention in the manpage related to the lexical sorting so thanks for this bit of information, it makes sense now (something like using `sort` without the `-n` flag, behavior is the same)

Comment: My join(1) man page says "Important: FILE1 and FILE2 must be sorted on the join fields." plus more information. Are you asking *why* does join require the files to be sorted? For efficiency/accuracy I suppose: the join kind of turns into a merge if the files are sorted.